# Issues scraping EV/EBITDA, Sale of Purchase Stock & Net Borrowings from Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I pulled a [Python script](https://github.com/vincentjs/oshaughnessey) off of Github which is intended to analyze & rank stocks. I finally got it running but unfortunately the EV/EBITDA and Shareholder Yield are populating their default values, 1000 & 0 respectively.

I've spent the last few days attempting to troubleshoot, learning a lot in the process, but unfortunately had no luck.. I *think* it's attempting to extract data from a nonexistent line on the 'Scraper' portion or referencing an incorrect HTML. I'll paste the two code snips I think the error may lie within though the rest of the files are linked above.

**Main File**

```
from sys import stdout

from Stock import Stock
import Pickler
import Scraper
import Rankings
import Fixer
import Writer

# HTML error code handler - importing data is a chore, and getting a connection
# error halfway through is horribly demotivating. Use a pickler to serialize
# imported data into a hot-startable database.
pklFileName = 'tmpstocks.pkl'
pickler = Pickler.Pickler()

# Check if a pickled file exists. Load it if the user requests. If no file
# loaded, stocks is an empty list.
stocks = pickler.loadPickledFile(pklFileName)

# Scrape data from FINVIZ. Certain presets have been established (see direct
# link for more details)
url = 'http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&f=cap_smallover&' + \
    'ft=4&c=0,1,2,6,7,10,11,13,14,45,65'
html = Scraper.importHtml(url)

# Parse the HTML for the number of pages from which we'll pull data
nPages = -1
for line in html:
    if line[0:40] == '<option selected="selected" value=1>Page':
        # Find indices
        b1 = line.index('/') + 1
        b2 = b1 + line[b1:].index('<')
        # Number of pages containing stock data
        nPages = int(line[b1:b2])
        break

# Parse data from table on the first page of stocks and store in the database,
# but only if no data was pickled
if pickler.source == Pickler.PickleSource.NOPICKLE:
    Scraper.importFinvizPage(html, stocks)

# The first page of stocks (20 stocks) has been imported. Now import the
# rest of them
source = Pickler.PickleSource.FINVIZ
iS = pickler.getIndex(source, 1, nPages + 1)

for i in range(iS, nPages + 1):
    try:
        # Print dynamic progress message
        print('Importing FINVIZ metrics from page ' + str(i) + ' of ' + \
            str(nPages) + '...', file=stdout, flush=True)

        # Scrape data as before
        url = 'http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&f=cap_smallover&ft=4&r=' + \
            str(i*20+1) + '&c=0,1,2,6,7,10,11,13,14,45,65'
        html = Scraper.importHtml(url)

        # Import stock metrics from page into a buffer
        bufferList = []
        Scraper.importFinvizPage(html, bufferList)

        # If no errors encountered, extend buffer to stocks list
        stocks.extend(bufferList)
    except:
        # Error encountered. Pickle stocks for later loading
        pickler.setError(source, i, stocks)
        break


# FINVIZ stock metrics successfully imported
print('\n')

# Store number of stocks in list
nStocks = len(stocks)

# Handle pickle file
source = Pickler.PickleSource.YHOOEV
iS = pickler.getIndex(source, 0, nStocks)

# Grab EV/EBITDA metrics from Yahoo! Finance
for i in range(iS, nStocks):
    try:
        # Print dynamic progress message
        print('Importing Key Statistics for ' + stocks[i].tick +
            ' (' + str(i) + '/' + str(nStocks - 1) + ') from Yahoo! Finance...', \
            file=stdout, flush=True)

        # Scrape data from Yahoo! Finance
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=' + stocks[i].tick + '+Key+Statistics'
        html = Scraper.importHtml(url)

        # Parse data
        for line in html:
            # Check no value
            if 'There is no Key Statistics' in line or \
            'Get Quotes Results for' in line or \
            'Changed Ticker Symbol' in line or \
            '</html>' in line:
                # Non-financial file (e.g. mutual fund) or
                # Ticker not located or
                # End of html page
                stocks[i].evebitda = 1000
                break
            elif 'Enterprise Value/EBITDA' in line:
                # Line contains EV/EBITDA data
                evebitda = Scraper.readYahooEVEBITDA(line)
                stocks[i].evebitda = evebitda
                break
    except:
        # Error encountered. Pickle stocks for later loading
        pickler.setError(source, i, stocks)
        break


# Yahoo! Finance EV/EBITDA successfully imported
print('\n')

# Handle pickle file
source = Pickler.PickleSource.YHOOBBY
iS = pickler.getIndex(source, 0, nStocks)

# Grab BBY metrics from Yahoo! Finance
for i in range(iS, nStocks):
    try:
        # Print dynamic progress message
        print('Importing Cash Flow for ' + stocks[i].tick +
            ' (' + str(i) + '/' + str(nStocks - 1) + ') from Yahoo! Finance...', \
            file=stdout, flush=True)

        # Scrape data from Yahoo! Finance
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s=' + stocks[i].tick + '&ql=1'
        html = Scraper.importHtml(url)

        # Parse data
        totalBuysAndSells = 0
        for line in html:
            # Check no value
            if 'There is no Cash Flow' in line or \
            'Get Quotes Results for' in line or \
            'Changed Ticker Symbol' in line or \
            '</html>' in line:
                # Non-financial file (e.g. mutual fund) or
                # Ticker not located or
                # End of html page
                break
            elif 'Sale Purchase of Stock' in line:
                # Line contains Sale/Purchase of Stock information
                totalBuysAndSells = Scraper.readYahooBBY(line)
                break

        # Calculate BBY as a percentage of current market cap
        bby = round(-totalBuysAndSells / stocks[i].mktcap * 100, 2)
        stocks[i].bby = bby
    except:
        # Error encountered. Pickle stocks for later loading
        pickler.setError(source, i, stocks)
        break


# Yahoo! Finance BBY successfully imported

if not pickler.hasErrorOccurred:
    # All data imported
    print('\n')
    print('Fixing screener errors...')

    # A number of stocks may have broken metrics. Fix these (i.e. assign out-of-
    # bounds values) before sorting
    stocks = Fixer.fixBrokenMetrics(stocks)

    print('Ranking stocks...')

    # Calculate shareholder Yield
    for i in range(nStocks):
        stocks[i].shy = stocks[i].div + stocks[i].bby

    # Time to rank! Lowest value gets 100
    rankPE = 100 * (1 - Rankings.rankByValue([o.pe for o in stocks]) / nStocks)
    rankPS = 100 * (1 - Rankings.rankByValue([o.ps for o in stocks]) / nStocks)
    rankPB = 100 * (1 - Rankings.rankByValue([o.pb for o in stocks]) / nStocks)
    rankPFCF = 100 * (1 - Rankings.rankByValue([o.pfcf for o in stocks]) / nStocks)
    rankEVEBITDA = 100 * (1 - Rankings.rankByValue([o.evebitda for o in stocks]) / nStocks)

    # Shareholder yield ranked with highest getting 100
    rankSHY = 100 * (Rankings.rankByValue([o.shy for o in stocks]) / nStocks)

    # Rank total stock valuation
    rankStock = rankPE + rankPS + rankPB + rankPFCF + rankEVEBITDA + rankSHY

    # Rank 'em
    rankOverall = Rankings.rankByValue(rankStock)
    # Calculate Value Composite - higher the better
    valueComposite = 100 * rankOverall / len(rankStock)
    # Reverse indices - lower index -> better score
    rankOverall = [len(rankStock) - 1 - x for x in rankOverall]

    # Assign to stocks
    for i in range(nStocks):
        stocks[i].rank = rankOverall[i]
        stocks[i].vc = round(valueComposite[i], 2)

    print('Sorting stocks...')

    # Sort all stocks by normalized rank
    stocks = [x for (y, x) in sorted(zip(rankOverall, stocks))]

    # Sort top decile by momentum factor. O'Shaughnessey historically uses 25
    # stocks to hold. The top decile is printed, and the user may select the top 25
    # (or any n) from the .csv file.
    dec = int(nStocks / 10)
    topDecile = []

    # Store temporary momentums from top decile for sorting reasons
    moms = [o.mom for o in stocks[:dec]]

    # Sort top decile by momentum
    for i in range(dec):
        # Get index of top momentum performer in top decile
        topMomInd = moms.index(max(moms))
        # Sort
        topDecile.append(stocks[topMomInd])
        # Remove top momentum performer from further consideration
        moms[topMomInd] = -100

    print('Saving stocks...')

    # Save momentum-weighted top decile
    topCsvPath = 'top.csv'
    Writer.writeCSV(topCsvPath, topDecile)

    # Save results to .csv
    allCsvPath = 'stocks.csv'
    Writer.writeCSV(allCsvPath, stocks)

    print('\n')
    print('Complete.')
    print('Top decile (sorted by momentum) saved to: ' + topCsvPath)
    print('All stocks (sorted by trending value) saved to: ' + allCsvPath)
```

**Scraper**

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen

from Stock import Stock

def importHtml(url):
    "Scrapes the HTML file from the given URL and returns line break delimited \
    strings"

    response = urlopen(url, data = None)
    html = response.read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')

    return html

def importFinvizPage(html, stocks):
    "Imports data from a FINVIZ HTML page and stores in the list of Stock \
    objects"

    isFound = False

    for line in html:
        if line[0:15] == '<td height="10"':
            isFound = True
            # Import data line into stock database
            _readFinvizLine(line, stocks)

        if isFound and len(line) < 10:
            break

    return

def _readFinvizLine(line, stocks):
    "Imports stock metrics from the data line and stores it in the list of \
    Stock objects"

    # Parse html
    (stkraw, dl) = _parseHtml(line)

    # Create new stock object
    stock = Stock()

    # Get ticker symbol
    stock.tick = stkraw[dl[1] + 1: dl[2]]
    # Get company name
    stock.name = stkraw[dl[2] + 1 : dl[3]]

    # Get market cap multiplier (either MM or BB)
    if stkraw[dl[4] - 1] == 'B':
        capmult = 1000000000
    else:
        capmult = 1000000

    # Get market cap
    stock.mktcap = capmult * _toFloat(stkraw[dl[3] + 1 : dl[4] - 1])
    # Get P/E ratio
    stock.pe = _toFloat(stkraw[dl[4] + 1 : dl[5]])
    # Get P/S ratio
    stock.ps = _toFloat(stkraw[dl[5] + 1 : dl[6]])
    # Get P/B ratio
    stock.pb = _toFloat(stkraw[dl[6] + 1 : dl[7]])
    # Get P/FCF ratio
    stock.pfcf = _toFloat(stkraw[dl[7] + 1 : dl[8]])
    # Get Dividend Yield
    stock.div = _toFloat(stkraw[dl[8] + 1 : dl[9] - 1])
    # Get 6-mo Relative Price Strength
    stock.mom = _toFloat(stkraw[dl[9] + 1 : dl[10] - 1])
    # Get Current Stock Price
    stock.price = _toFloat(stkraw[dl[11] + 1 : dl[12]])

    # Append stock to list of stocks
    stocks.append(stock)

    return

def _toFloat(line):
    "Converts a string to a float. Returns NaN if the line can't be converted"

    try:
        num = float(line)
    except:
        num = float('NaN')

    return num

def readYahooEVEBITDA(line):
    "Returns EV/EBITDA data from Yahoo! Finance HTML line"

    # Parse html
    (stkraw, dl) = _parseHtml(line)

    for i in range(0, len(dl)):
        if (stkraw[dl[i] + 1 : dl[i] + 24] == 'Enterprise Value/EBITDA'):
            evebitda = stkraw[dl[i + 1] + 1 : dl[i + 2]]
            break

    return _toFloat(evebitda)

def readYahooBBY(line):
    "Returns total buys and sells from Yahoo! Finance HTML line. Result will \
    still need to be divided by market cap"

    # Line also contains Borrowings details - Remove it all
    if 'Net Borrowings' in line:
        # Remove extra data
        line = line[:line.find('Net Borrowings')]

    # Trim prior data
    line = line[line.find('Sale Purchase of Stock'):]

    # Determine if buys or sells, replace open parantheses:
    # (#,###) -> -#,###
    line = re.sub(r'[(]', '-', line)

    # Eliminate commas and close parantheses: -#,### -> -####
    line = re.sub(r'[,|)]', '', line)

    # Remove HTML data and markup, replacing with commas
    line = re.sub(r'[<.*?>|]', ',', line)
    line = re.sub('&nbsp;', ',', line)

    # Locate the beginnings of each quarterly Sale Purchase points
    starts = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(',\d+,|,.\d+', line)]

    # Locate the ends of each quarterly Sale Purchase points
    ends = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('\d,', line)]

    # Sum all buys and sells across year
    tot = 0
    for i in range(0, len(starts)):
        # x1000 because all numbers are in thousands
        tot = tot + float(line[starts[i] + 1 : ends[i] + 1]) * 1000

    return tot

def _parseHtml(line):
    "Parses the HTML line by </td> breaks and returns the delimited string"

    # Replace </td> breaks with placeholder, '`'
    ph = '`'
    rem = re.sub('</td>', ph, line)

    # The ticker symbol initial delimiter is different
    # Remove all other remaining HTML data
    stkraw = re.sub('<.*?>', '', rem)

    # Replace unbalanced HTML
    stkraw = re.sub('">', '`', stkraw)

    # Find the placeholders
    dl = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(ph, stkraw)]

    return (stkraw, dl)
```

If anyone has any input or perhaps a better method such as beautifulsoup, I'd really appreciate it! I'm very open to any tutorials that would help as well. My intent is to both better my programming ability and have an effective stock screener.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue scraping the Yahoo data in Python, and in Matlab as well. As a workaround, I wrote a macro in VBA to grab all of the EV/EBITDA data from Yahoo by visiting each stock's Key Statistics page. However, it takes about a day to run on all 3,000+ stocks with market caps over $200M, which is not really practical.

I've tried finding the EV/EBITDA on various stock screeners online, but they either don't report it or only let you download a couple hundred stocks' data without paying. Busy Stock's screener seems the best in this regard, but their EV/EBITDA figures don't line up to Yahoo's, which worries me that they are using different methodology.

One solution and my recommendation to you is to use the Trending Value algorithm in Quantopian, which is free. You can find the code here: https://www.quantopian.com/posts/oshaugnessy-what-works-on-wall-street
Quantopian will let you backtest the algorithm to 2002, and live test it as well.